# Notepad++ add number in each line

Tags: notepad++

I have the following data in a text file

```
p=1
p=1
p=1
p=1
```

etc. I open that file in Notepad++.

How would I change it to

```
p=1
p=2
p=3
p=4
```

etc.

Comment: I guess I understand what you mean but I don't think it's a job for regex. You would better use a script for doing this kind of replacement.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can use the "Column Editor" mode. First, select the column you want by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and dragging down the column. Then go to "Edit->Column Editor", you will get a box that looks like this:

[image]

Choose the "Number to Insert" button, then choose the starting value and the increment. It will replace the column with the values you want.

Comment: For keyboardists column selection is done with Shift + Alt + arrow keys.  You can select a zero width column to insert data, e.g. numbering a list.  https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html

Comment: And, at least as of Notepad++ 7.5.9, you can bring up the Column Editor pop up with Alt-C.

Comment: This pads to the right of the numbers to match right shift of larger numbers. I used an [online script](https://www.browserling.com/tools/number-lines) instead.

Comment: Do you why this doesn't work for me? Maybe I select wrongly?

Comment: Leave the **repeat** text input box for latest notepad++ versions ..