# remove characters between 2 character in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

i want remove characters between ", R.drawable   and  );  in notepad++

```
case  : ed.getText().insert(ed.getSelectionStart(), getSmiledText(getBaseContext(), "", R.drawable.em_1f31e);
case  : ed.getText().insert(ed.getSelectionStart(), getSmiledText(getBaseContext(), "", R.drawable.em_1f320);
case  : ed.getText().insert(ed.getSelectionStart(), getSmiledText(getBaseContext(), "", R.drawable.em_1f330);
case  : ed.getText().insert(ed.getSelectionStart(), getSmiledText(getBaseContext(), "", R.drawable.em_1f331);
case  : ed.getText().insert(ed.getSelectionStart(), getSmiledText(getBaseContext(), "", R.drawable.em_1f332);
```

and want change case to case number like this :

```
case 10  : ed.getText().insert(ed.getSelectionStart(), getSmiledText(getBaseContext(), "", R.drawable.em_1f31e);
case 11 : ed.getText().insert(ed.getSelectionStart(), getSmiledText(getBaseContext(), "", R.drawable.em_1f320);
case 12 : ed.getText().insert(ed.getSelectionStart(), getSmiledText(getBaseContext(), "", R.drawable.em_1f330);
case 13 : ed.getText().insert(ed.getSelectionStart(), getSmiledText(getBaseContext(), "", R.drawable.em_1f331);
case 14 : ed.getText().insert(ed.getSelectionStart(), getSmiledText(getBaseContext(), "", R.drawable.em_1f332);
```

begin from 10 to * . this possible ?

Comment: For the second question, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26224391/372239

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part of your question select Regular Expression in the Find Replace and Find:

```
(R.drawable).+(\);)
```

and Replace with:

```
\1\2
```

The second part can be done by holding alt and selecting the column then going Edit->Column Editor and playing with Number to Insert.

Answer (score 1):

This line in AWK inserts number of row if the row is greater or equal to 10:

 `awk '{ i++; if(i>=10){ print $1, i, $0} else print }' your_file.txt`

You can do it easy in JAVA reading lines with BufferedReader. After you read a line, just split it with ' ' and check if the row is greater than 9, if it is then add a number line after first word