# Notepad++/Vim Incremental Insert

Tags: vim, insert, notepad++, increment

I have a file that I'm writing where I need to insert incrementing numbers in two different places (**Context** & **UConfig**). I've tried using the column editor in Notepad++, but it also adds numbers in the middle of the other rows.

```
forw mte Context 0  
forw mte Config 1 0 0  
forw mte CellSelection 10000  [10]  
forw mte UConfig 1([100000000000000 2] [] [] []) [] [0]  
forw mte ConfigCapability [1] [100] [100]  
forw mte ConfigSelection 20000
```

I need to copy this selection 1000 times with **Context** going from `0-999` and **UConfig** going from `100000000000000-100000000000999`.

Comment: I reopened question. Because it is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178151/notepad-add-number-in-each-line. The solution in that answer won't solve OP's problem. the Notepad++'s Column-mode doesn't help on this Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be an easy task for vim:

type:

```
qq?Conte<CR>6YGgpn<C-A>3jf0<C-A>q
```

then do `998@q`

- first step is record a macro `<CR> and <C-A>` means pressing `Enter and Ctrl-A`
- 2nd step is to replay the macro 998 times
- "what does the first line do exactly"? try by yourself from first `?` till last `<c-a>` you will see how the text was modified

Following is a demo, to show add the text from 0 - 4 (after recording, press `3@q`):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the amazing response. It works great except when I have a number like 26280052223000 in UConfig. When i try to increment it, it turns into 63322353. I think this may be an issue with the number being read as octal or hex?

Comment: you can try change the `f0` into `f[l`

Comment: That didn't seem to help, I've also tried removing octal and hex from nrformats, but I'm still encountering that problem.

Comment: in a new buffer type `26280052223000`, then move your cursor on it, press `Ctrl-A` (normal mode), does it change into `26280052223001`?

Comment: Seems like nothing happens now... `Ctrl-A` still works in the original buffer where I'm seeing the error though.

Comment: Ignore that, when I do `Ctrl-A` in a new buffer it turns into 3442306073. I have no idea what's going on.