# Automatically wrap custom XML tags and numbering them

Tags: xml, notepad++, sublimetext3, sublimetext2

I have a dialogue script for a game that needs to be formatted in XML, with following format...

```
<line id='1'> .............. </line>
<line id='2'> .............. </line>
<line id='3'> .............. </line>
....
<line id='n'> .............. </line>
```

Dialogue script I've given right now is written in plain format, I only need to wrap each lines in XML tags above.

Is there a way to automate the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in two steps.  First, add a line number to the start of each line of your text file.  Then, wrap each line in the `<line>` XML tags which you need.

To generate line numbers, you can use column editor mode.  First, insert a space the start of each line via this find and replacement:

**Find:**

```
(.*)
```

**Replace:**

```
 $1 (single space followed by $1)
```

Then use column editor mode to insert a generated line number at the start of each line.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178151/notepad-add-number-in-each-line) for more information on how to do this.  At this point, your data should look something like this:

```
1 Here is line one.
2 Here is line two.
3 Here is line three.
...
111 Here is line one hundred eleven.
```

Now you can do a second find and replacement to wrap each line in the `<line>` tag:

**Find:**

```
([0-9]+)\s+(.*)
```

**Replace:**

```
<line id='$1'>$2</line>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have trouble getting it to work. First step give me an "s" in each lines and the second step does not wrap all lines with the tags (only line 1-9).. Can you test with following sample? https://pastebin.com/mYzeedSV Note that the quote mark is still needed.

Comment: @Ran_TH I had a typo.  Please try my answer again.

Comment: Okay now it works! But when adding line numbers it adds double space to line 1-9, hence there's a blank space in final result. https://i.imgur.com/dPNMahh.jpg

Comment: Then use `([0-9]+)\s+(.*)` to consume all spaces between the line number and text.  I wasn't sure if you wanted to preserve original leading whitespace on each line.