# Add xml tag with line numbers to each line

Tags: xml, notepad++

I have a text file with 500 lines of text. I need to add xml tags to each line. 
For example I need to convert

```
sentence 
another sentence
another sentence
```

to

```
<line id="x1">sentence</line>
<line id="x2">another sentence</line>
<line id="x3">another sentence</line>
```

I tried the solution on [Automatically wrap custom XML tags and numbering them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46761958/automatically-wrap-custom-xml-tags-and-numbering-them?noredirect=1&lq=1) 
but it only numbers the tags till the 9th line (  ) 
I tried changing the term in find from ([0-9]+)\s+(.*) to ([0-999]+)\s+(.*) and ([000-999]+)\s+(.*), no matter what i try, I cant get it pass the ninth line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directions from the link worked for me, however, the reason that it only goes to 9 is because after 9, after using the Column Editor to add the numbers, the lines look like this:

```
1 sentence 
2 another sentence
3 another sentence
4 another sentence
5 another sentence
6 another sentence
7 another sentence
8 another sentence
9 another sentence
10another sentence // note no space after 9 here!
11another sentence
12another sentence
13another sentence
14another sentence
15another sentence
```

So, the FIRST thing to do, is to use the Column Editor, use the `Text to Insert` option, to add a space to the beginning of EVERY line. (make sure that the cursor is at the start of line 1)

Then, after the space is added, use the Column Editor again to add the numbers to EVERY line. (again, make sure that the cursor is at the start of line 1)
Use the `Number to Insert` option (set `Initial number` to 1, `Increase by` to 1), so that all the lines get numbered, and should look similar to this:

```
1  sentence 
2  another sentence
3  another sentence
4  another sentence
5  another sentence
6  another sentence
7  another sentence
8  another sentence
9  another sentence
10 another sentence
11 another sentence
12 another sentence
13 another sentence
14 another sentence
15 another sentence
```

After those 2 steps, then use the regex from the link you have should work. Note that the replacement regex from your link was slightly modified to add the `x` with the id that you want included:
`<line id='x$1'>$2</line>`

After formatting and using the slightly modified replacement regex from your link to the lines above, this was the final output:

```
<line id='x1'>sentence </line>
<line id='x2'>another sentence</line>
<line id='x3'>another sentence</line>
<line id='x4'>another sentence</line>
<line id='x5'>another sentence</line>
<line id='x6'>another sentence</line>
<line id='x7'>another sentence</line>
<line id='x8'>another sentence</line>
<line id='x9'>another sentence</line>
<line id='x10'>another sentence</line>
<line id='x11'>another sentence</line>
<line id='x12'>another sentence</line>
<line id='x13'>another sentence</line>
<line id='x14'>another sentence</line>
<line id='x15'>another sentence</line>
```