# Notepad++ - Replace all array indexes incrementally

Tags: replace, notepad++

I need to get rid of specific discovered_items from an array. An item that is incremented incorrectly causes the array to fail.

I have an array with varying digits that goes over 15000+, starting at one digit (0), all the way to five digits (example 13802), but the value that follows the colon has to remain. Say records 9000-11000 get taken out, I'd like to incrementally redo the whole numbering. How can I replace the values only inside the bracket ? If notepad++ cannot do it, is there a different program / method ?

```
discovered_items[13802]: 3629890649953796096
```

Comment: Your question is prety unclear. Could give a sample text and expected result?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178151/notepad-add-number-in-each-line/26224391?