# Increment xml value in the next row in Notepad++

Tags: xml, notepad++, generator, autofill

I am looking to add elements to my XML document.
A single element should be duplicated, while also incrementing its value - by using Notepad++.

#### Example XML

Like below the `<rateCode>` element was duplicated incrementing values by 1:

```xml
<rateCode>1</rateCode>
<rateCode>2</rateCode>
<rateCode>3</rateCode>
```

and so on till 1000.

Is there any way to achieve this in Notepad++ ?

Comment: you can do it via excel and copy it to required place. using SEQUENCE(1000) for number in excel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notepad++ add number in each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178151/notepad-add-number-in-each-line)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

Use a number generator and copy-paste ( https://numbergenerator.org/numberlist/1-1000 )

In Notepad++, use 'Search | Replace` regex:

Find what: `^(\d+)$`
Replace with: `<rateCode>\1</rateCode>`
Replace All

Comment: That's a KISS (keep it simple stupid) approach. Would prefer this to generate simple files from scratch. It basically generates a number of specified rows, which are then enhanced with static content - where simple must apply to the static content (the regex-replacement).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [**macro**](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/macros/) in Notepad++ to achieve this **autofilling**.

Or you can also use the [*Python Script* plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) like described here:
[How to write macro for Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362444/how-to-write-macro-for-notepad)

```py
# append a new XML element with incremented value
for i in range(1, 1000):
     editor.appendText("<rateCode>{}</rateCode>\r\n".format(i));
```

When new to Python programming get a brief introduction to implementing loops in Python, e.g. [*For Loop*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)